# SMS-шлюз без необходимости согласовывать имени отправителя.

Tags: gate, sms, шлюз

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть SMS шлюзы с возможностью отправки сообщений с произвольным именем отправителя без необходимости предварительного согласования?

Пожелание:

```
- отсутствие необходимости согласовывать каждое имя отправителя;
- наличие АПИ;
- поддержка стран России, Украины, Казахстана, Белоруссии и других;
- возможность пополнения баланса с помощью webmoney;
```

Благодарю за ответы.

С уважением, Дмитрий.

Comment: прямо рай для спаммера.

Comment: Мне для личного пользования (не более 10 сообщений в сутки). Просто нету желания ждать каждый раз.